# Automatically scrape multiple questions from quora with a specific tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, quora

I want to scrape questions from the Quora related to some specific topic which has more than 4 answers or so.

I want to find the

a) Number of answers

b) tags associated with each question

This is my program :

```
res=requests.get("https://www.quora.com/How-does-Quora-automatically-know-what-tags-to-put-for-a-question")

soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
# All the ans inside pagedlist_item
ans=soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'pagedlist_item'})


#Question Name inside question_text_edit
qname=soup.find('div', {'class' : 'question_text_edit'})
#qnam=soup.find('div', {'class' : 'question_text_edit'})


#Tag of Question
tags=soup.find('div', {'class' : 'QuestionTopicHorizontalList TopicList'})



#checking to see if "TV" is the tag of the question in the current webpage 
#Also, checking if no. of answers of the given question >=4, if yes then print the question
#logic for checking the conditions
no_ans=0;
if "TV" in tags.text:
    print(i.text)
    for a in ans:
        no_ans=no_ans+1
    if no_ans>=4:
        print(qname.text)
```

I want to search over many such pages which have the tag `TV` and then later perform the check over those pages to satisfy the above condition.

The logic for checking the conditions is present at the end of the code. But, this will work only for **one question** in the webpage whose address is inside the `requests.get("")` function.

How can I let the code automatically iterate over many web pages(multiple questions) with the tag as 'TV' rather than passing a single webpage address into `requests.get("")` function ?

Also, I want to scrape multiple questions(as many as 40 or so).

Comment: Start by taking a look at `curl`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Can't `BeautifulSoup` help me in doing that ?

Comment: Yup, you can also start taking a look at BeautifulSoup

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I hope the question is well defined now!! I'm not able to ask new questions with so many `downvotes` even after the `EDIT` !!

Comment: The way this question reads now, it sounds like “I have some code that solves part of the problem; can you guys supply the rest of the code to solve my whole problem, for free?”. That probably explains the downvotes. No one wants to be treated like a free code-writing service! It might also be explained by the fact that the “solution” seems trivial and must have occurred to you: to find a list of pages on TV, you should first learn how you, a human, would find this list “normally”, by navigating the site with your browser. Then write code to automate this. That is “take a look at BeautfulSoup”

Comment: @DanBron Well !! I never asked for code. I only want the approach to do what I need. Rest I will do.

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi The approach is as I described it: find out what you, a human, would do manually to get a list of all these pages, then automate the process of building that list. For example, if you, as a human, have to click on the [TV] tag on the Quora article to get a list of all Quora questions about television, then you now know you have to build a bot to click that tag for you. Seems simple enough to me, and I don’t know what’s missing that you’re asking for help here about. Whatever it is you as a person would do to do this manually, automate that.

Comment: I got you. You mean an automation system kind of thing that can automatically do what a human would do? Can you kindly help me know the framework that I would need to that?

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi You don’t need a framework. Just write the code. There’s nothing special about this problem. This is everyday programming. This is largely what programs do, what they’re written for in the first place: to automate tasks that otherwise humans would have to do.

Comment: @DanBron Sir, Thanks for the help. I hope answering that can now help me in removing “You have reached your question limit”  for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer these step by step :

`I want to search over many such pages which have the tag TV and then later perform the check over those pages to satisfy the above condition.`

Well, If you want to scrape multiple pages like these, you have to start from the root page of the topic which has many questions related to that specific topic and begin scraping the links of these questions enlisted in that root page.

`Also, I want to scrape multiple questions(as many as 40 or so)`

For this, you need to mimic scrolling so that you can find more and more questions as you go down.

You can't directly use `Requests`, `BeautifulSoup` to execute events like mimicking the scrolling operation. Here is a piece of code that I have in Python using the `Selenium` library to fulfill your requirements.

**Note**:

1. Install [Chrome driver for your chrome version](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/).
2. install selenium using `pip install -U selenium`.
3. If you are using windows - executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver.exe'

This code asks for 2 links and then starts scraping the "**Question,No. of answers,Tags,4 answers**" and saves them in the **csv** format.

`Keys.PAGE_DOWN` is used for mimicking the scroll button. 
  Different details have been appended to the `row` list and at the end it is saved 
  into the `csv` file.

Also, you can change the value of `no_of_pagedowns` variable to increase no. of 
  scrolls you want.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv


with open('submission.csv','w') as file:
    file.write("Question,No. of answers,Tags,4 answers")

link1 = input("Enter first link")
#link2 = input("Enter second link")
manylinks = list()
manylinks.append(link1)
#manylinks.append(link2)
for olink in manylinks:
    qlinks = list()    
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/ajay/Downloads/chromedriver')
    browser.get(olink)
    time.sleep(1)
    elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")


    no_of_pagedowns = 50
    while no_of_pagedowns:
        elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        no_of_pagedowns-=1
    post_elems =browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='question_link']")
    for post in post_elems:
        qlink = post.get_attribute("href")
        print(qlink)
        qlinks.append(qlink)

    for qlink in qlinks:

        append_status=0

        row = list()

        browser.get(qlink)
        time.sleep(1)


        elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")


        no_of_pagedowns = 1
        while no_of_pagedowns:
            elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            no_of_pagedowns-=1


        #Question Names
        qname =browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='question_text_edit']")
        for q in qname:
            print(q.text)
            row.append(q.text)


        #Answer Count    
        no_ans = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='answer_count']")
    #    print("No. of ans :")
        for count in no_ans:
    #        print(count.text)
            append_status = int(count.text[:2])

            row.append(count.text)

        #Tags
        tags = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='header']")
    #    print("\nTag :")
        tag_field = list()
        for t in tags:
            tag_field.append(t.text)
    #        print(t.text,'\n')
        row.append(tag_field)


        #All answers
        all_ans=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui_qtext_expanded']")
        i=1
        answer_field = list()
        for post in all_ans:
            if i<=4:
                i=i+1
    #            print("Answer : ")
    #            print(post.text)
                answer_field.append(post.text)
            else:
                break   
        row.append(answer_field)


        print('append_status',append_status)

        if append_status >= 4:
            with open('submission.csv','a') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(row)
```